# Script tag loading inside Iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, script-tag

I've been trying to find an answer to this but could never find one:

I have four iframes loading on a parent page. Each of these I frames have javascript to be executed (slightly different JS in each one).

Currently, I've bundled all that JS into one file, which is in  tag in each of the frames.

The behaviour I see is that the browser emits only one request to that script, since it's the same in each frame.

My question is: What if I wanted smaller bundles, by splitting that JS file into 4 smaller ones. how are script tags loaded inside an iframe ?

If they're loaded async: I might gain some performance from it. 
If they're loaded one after the other: Then having a larger bundle and avoiding multiple round trips might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iframes work almost exactly like parent pages do. Think of it like opening up several tabs in your browser at the same time, each one tries to load as quickly as possible, independent of the other pages.

Using a single large bundle means that once it has finished downloading in any iframe, the browser will cache it and all other iframes requesting it will load faster from the cache.

Using smaller bundles means that each iframe might finish load sooner if it's particular script finishes before the other iframes, but there's no guarantee which order they'll finish. They'll all try to asynchronously load their respective files.

Comment: since the 4 iframes are appended at the same time, why do I only see one request sent to the bundle ?

I understand that it would be cached if it was first loaded in an iframe and then in the others, but if it's async, wouldnt they start fetching the same asset at the same time ?

Maybe browsers are intelligent enough to see a particular source is being fetched currently ?

Comment: The browser checks for duplicate requests and automatically merges them. You can test this out by making a page with several large images loading from the same URL. Once one request is made, any duplicate URLs will simply piggyback on the same resource.